# Write on a file from a function - No output

Tags: python

I have a function and I would like part of the output in the my text file:

```
myfunc('text') = ['a', 'b']

mylist =[]
f = open("add.txt","w")

for elem in mylist:
    f.write(myfunc(elem)[0] + " " + myfunc(elem)[1])
```

But this does not make new lines

I would like to have in the output the first element, a space, the second element

and then on a new line the same but with other values for my function

But there is no output in "add.txt"

Comment: Add `+ '\n'` after `myfunc(elem)[1]`?

Comment: No, it does not output anything

Comment: ...is `mylist` really an empty list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an explicit newline with `f.write`. Also, you only need to call `myfunc` once, and string formatting would be preferable to string concatenation.

```
with open("add.txt", "w") as f:
    for elem in mylist:
        a, b = myfunc(elem)
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(a, b))
```

Comment: I am sorry. It does not work. The problem is that my function outputs a list ['a', 'b'] and I would like 'a' space 'b'

Comment: What *does* it do, then? `a, b = ...` unpacks the list returned by the function, and assigns the first element to `a` and the second element to `b`.